# Regex Substitution Ignoring Last 4 Characters

Tags: regex, substitution

I am new to regex so I need some help with an expression.  I have a string...

CO999O0XABCD

and I need to replace any instance of Letter "O" with Numeric "0" but only in the first 8 characters of the string as below...

C099900XABCD

I thought about just doing simple [O] with substitution to "0" and statistically, the last 4 digits are almost always alpha but I don't want to take the chance of changing an "O" to a "0" by mistake so isolating the match to just the first 8 characters is the goal.  The characters are OCR driven so that's the wildcard I'm trying to overcome by the substitution not affecting the last 4 characters.

Any help you can give would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: Please share the pattern you tried and please let us know what the programming language/regex flavor you are using.

Comment: If the string is of fixed length (12 chars) you may always subtring the text and only run replacement on the first 8 chars.

Comment: This isn't a job for regex. Use your language's string replacement if possible for something so simple.

Comment: .net would be the best regex flavor.  I am not a developer so regex is what I'm allowed to use so I don't have another option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use something else than regex than this pattern will work .NET (and JS) environments, assuming each string is at the beginning of a separate line:

```
O(?<=^.{0,8})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VkZNqg/1)